# SSL certs and Java Keystore encryption

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, keystore

This question may seem rather stupid but Im new to certs and java keystores. My client wants to know if you can have a 2048 SSL cert in a 1024 keystore. My thoughts are this wouldn't work but I have yet to find a sold answer anywhere.

So my question is can you have a SSL cert with 2048 encryption in a keystore with 1024 encryption and will it work? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "have an SSL cert with 2048 encryption in a keystore with 1024 encryption". But I'm guessing you meant that you are trying to store a 2048 bit SSL cert inside a keystore, which in turn encrypts the contents with a 1024 bit key (protected by a password that is). 

If this is the case, then you should have no problem doing it, since the keysize of the keystore is just used to protect the contents of the keystore, and AFAIK it has nothing to do with the actual keysizes of whatever you have inside the keystore.

Comment: Certificates arent encrypted at all in a KeyStore, only private keys or possibly key pairs.